# Type not resolving in multiple factories

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, factory, ioc-container

I have following class

```
public class NightlyJob : IScheduleJob, IRecurringJob
```

For both interfaces I have simple typed factories like this:

```
public interface IScheduleJobFactory
{
    IEnumerable<IScheduleJob> Create();
}
```

Mentioned class is not retrieved from both factories' .`Create()` methods. It seems that the class can be retrieved from only one factory depending on which of the interfaces in the signature is written first.

My question is if there is a way around this?

Comment: Why do you need a factory? They are [code smells](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Comment: Castle's typed factory seemed like an easiest way around. All I need to do is get implementations of an interface and choose one with matching property.

Comment: Why not inject `IEnumerable<IScheduleJob>` into your consumer(s)?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: So your actual question is: "How do I register a collection of IScheduleJob insrances?"?

Comment: So you can somehow pass `IEnumerable<X>` and have them resolved as all implementation types? I didn't know one can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching in the direction suggested by Steven in comments. I found my solution to be injecting `IEnumerable<IScheduleJob>` and `IEnumerable<IRecurringJob>` into the consumers directly. These are resolved as collections of implementations by using Castle's **CollectionResolver** like this:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("."))
                .BasedOn(typeof(IScheduleJob)).
                WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        );
```